# Assigning PHP variable to JavaScript variable, value is disappearing

Tags: javascript, php

I am attempting to assign a PHP variable to a JavaScript variable. When I do 'console.log(ca)'; the console logs it as being an empty variable. But if I click "view page source code" it shows the variable being set correctly.

JavaScript:

```
function checkAnswer(o, header) {
    x = document.getElementById(o);
    var ca = "<?php echo $value['a']; ?>";
    if (x.value == ca) {
        document.getElementById(header).className = 'header bg-green';
        console.log("test");
    } else {
        document.getElementById(header).className = 'header bg-red';
        console.log("User: " + x.value + " Answer: " + ca);
    }
}
```

Console Response:

> User: Driller Answer:

Page Source Code:

```
function checkAnswer(o, header) {
    x = document.getElementById(o);
    var ca = "Driller";
    if (x.value == ca) {
        document.getElementById(header).className = 'header bg-green';
        console.log("test");
    } else {
        document.getElementById(header).className = 'header bg-red';
        console.log("User: " + x.value + " Answer: " + ca);
    }
}
```

HTML/PHP that is calling the function:

```
<input type='radio' id='".$value['id']."1' name='".$value['id']."' value='".$value['o1']."' onChange='checkAnswer(\"".$value['id']."1\", \"header_".$value['id']."\")'/>
```

Comment: It seems that your javascript function is working properly but there is an error in passing arguments in onchange function.

Comment: check the parameters,
console.log(o);console.log(header);

Answer (score 0):

Can you help explain what you are trying to achieve?? as it is very unclear

x.value cannot equal "ca" from the description you gave.

Also you need to add the element with the id header_* to your question

```
<div id = 'header_" . $value['id'] ."'>

</div>
```

So that the onchange function can actually run.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are setting an element's property which does not exist in your DOM HTML.

That's why it is showing an error in console. [See Image]

[image]

You need to create an element of id `header` OR comment on the lines which are changing the `header's` class.

See below code which I have tested.

```
<?php
$value = array('id'=>1, 'o1' => 'Driller', 'a' => 'Driller');
echo "<input type='radio' id='" . $value['id'] . "1' name='" . $value['id'] . "' value='" . $value['o1'] . "' onChange='checkAnswer(\"" . $value['id'] . "1\", \"header_" . $value['id'] . "\")'/>
";
?>

<script>
    function checkAnswer(o, header) {
        x = document.getElementById(o);
        var ca = "<?php echo $value['a']; ?>";
        if (x.value == ca) {
            //document.getElementById(header).className = 'header bg-green';
            console.log("test");
        } else {
            //document.getElementById(header).className = 'header bg-red';
            console.log("User: " + x.value + " Answer: " + ca);
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Please ignore the skype message.